# Android fragment toolbar text not changing

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-toolbar

I am developing an app with `Fragment`. When I open the `Fragment` where not listed in navigation drawer. For example, I have 8 fragments where 7 fragments is listed in navigation drawer and the other one is not listed (`Fragment` name is sub category `Fragment`) in navigation drawer. I can change toolbar title of 7 `Fragment` using below code. But I cannot change the toolbar tittle of `Fragment` where not listed in navigation drawer.

My `HomeActivity.java`

```
public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements FragmentDrawer.FragmentDrawerListener {
    private Toolbar mToolbar;
    private FragmentDrawer drawerFragment;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
        mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        drawerFragment = (FragmentDrawer)
                getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer);
        drawerFragment.setUp(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer, (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout), mToolbar);
        drawerFragment.setDrawerListener(this);

        displayView(0);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawerItemSelected(View view, int position) {
        displayView(position);
    }

    public void displayView(int position) {
        Fragment fragment = null;
        String title = getString(R.string.app_name);
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                fragment = new HomeFragment();
                title = getString(R.string.title_home);
                Log.d("LOGTAG", "Home");
                break;
            case 1:
                fragment = new CategoriesFragment();
                title = getString(R.string.title_categories);
                Log.d("LOGTAG", "Categories");
                break;
            case 2:
                fragment = new MyOrdersFragment();
                title = getString(R.string.title_myorders);
                Log.d("LOGTAG", "My Orders");
                break;
            case 3:
                fragment = new WalletFragment();
                title = getString(R.string.title_wallet);
                Log.d("LOGTAG", "Wallet");
                break;
            case 4:
                fragment = new AccountSettingsFragment();
                title = getString(R.string.title_account_settings);
                Log.d("LOGTAG", "Account Settings");
                break;
            case 5:
                fragment = new AboutUsFragment();
                title = getString(R.string.title_aboutus);
                Log.d("LOGTAG", "About Us");
                break;
            case 6:
                fragment = new ContactUsFragment();
                title = getString(R.string.title_contactus);
                Log.d("LOGTAG", "Contact Us");
                break;
            case 7:
                fragment = new LogOutFragment();
                title = getString(R.string.title_logout);
                Log.d("LOGTAG", "Log out");
                break;
            case 8:
                fragment = new SubCategoryFragment();
                title = getString(R.string.title_sub_categories);
                Log.d("LOGTAG", "Sub Categories");
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        if (fragment != null) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container_body, fragment);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();

            // set the toolbar title
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
        }
    }

    public void loadFragment(int id, Fragment fragment) {
        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(id, fragment, fragment.toString());
        ft.addToBackStack(null);
        ft.commit();
    }
}
```

And the `SubCategoryFragment.java`

```
public class SubCategoryFragment extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {
    List<GetDataAdapter> GetDataAdapter1;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager recyclerViewlayoutManager;
    RecyclerView.Adapter recyclerViewadapter;

    String GET_JSON_DATA_HTTP_URL;
    String JSON_IMAGE_TITLE_NAME = "image_title";
    String JSON_IMAGE_URL = "image_url";
    String JSON_IMAGE_ID = "id";

    JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest ;
    RequestQueue requestQueue ;

    public SubCategoryFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sub_category, container, false);

        HomeActivity activity = new HomeActivity();
        activity.displayView(8); //Occuring error

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
    }
}
```

When I add `activity.displayView(8)` in sub category `Fragment` it shows error.

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference

So, how it possible to change `Toolbar` text?

Comment: this is how NOT to communicate to the parent Activity `HomeActivity activity = new HomeActivity();
    activity.displayView(8); //Occuring error` you should be using an interface an attach it in onAttach of Fragment, but anyways why in onCreateView are you trying to call the Activity method anyway? my point being that if the Fragment is already shown why would you call to displayView anyways

Comment: What is the another way to change text of toolbar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use this

```
((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setTitle("sub categories");
```

in place of

```
 HomeActivity activity = new HomeActivity();
        activity.displayView(8); //Occuring error
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set title like this.
In your subcategory fragment:

Toolbar mtoolbar;

In oncreate view(){

mtoolbar=(Toolbar)getActivity.findViewById(R.id.toolbarid);

setSupportAcrionbar(mtoolbar):

}

Then in onActivityCreated(){

((HomeActvity) getSupportAcrionbar.settitle("your title"));

}

Answer (score 0):

In Kotlin you can use the following:

```
(activity as AppCompatActivity).supportActionBar?.title = "Title here"
```